# Jquery function work on only the 1st row but fail on the following rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now, the code only work on the 1st row but fail to work on the following rows, any ideas?

```js
if (typeof set == "undefined") {
  var set = $(".url").val();
}
$(".addSkip").on('click', function() {

  $(".url").val(set + $("#name").val());


});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td><input type="date" size="15" name="date[]" class="start_date" \>
      <input type="button" size="10" value="confirm date" class="addSkip"></td>
    <td>Nextdate<input type="text" value="100" id="name" size="15" name="nextdate[]" class="end_date" \> </td>

    <td>traditionalmessage<textarea rows="3" cols="20" readonly class="url" name="traditionalmessage[]">traditionalmessage</textarea> </td>
    
       <td>simplifiedmessage<textarea rows="3" cols="20" readonly class="url" name="simplified[]">simplifiedmessage</textarea> </td>
     <td>engmessage<textarea rows="3" cols="20" readonly class="url" name="engmessage[]">engmessage</textarea> </td>
    
    </tr>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and incomplete snippet.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah, you should start by fixing that HTML mess. You can not have td as a child of table, and `</td><tr><td></tr>` does not make any sense either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with classname instead of `id` .And find the element us `$(this).closest('tr').find(".url")`

1. [`closest()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjAjLrW0-zUAhUBtI8KHXCVDo0QFggxMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fclosest%2F&usg=AFQjCNGkhpVv76EWvWWYjEID4qvdUghHMQ) match the parent of `tr`
2. [`find()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjspfeF1OzUAhWHp48KHbusDqwQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ffind%2F&usg=AFQjCNG-8t8FlAFURjmRfahbB_JtshKgfg) match the children element inside
3. And your html is not proper alignment

**Updated**

```js
if (typeof set == "undefined") {
  var set = $(".url").val();
}
$(".addSkip").on('click', function() {

  $(this).closest('tr').find(".url").eq(0).val(set + $(this).closest('tr').find(".end_date").val());

});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td><input type="date" size="15" name="date[]" class="start_date" \>
      <input type="button" size="10" value="confirm date" class="addSkip"></td>
    <td>Nextdate<input type="text" value="100" id="name" size="15" name="nextdate[]" class="end_date" \> </td>

    <td>traditionalmessage<textarea rows="3" cols="20" readonly class="url" name="traditionalmessage[]">traditionalmessage</textarea> </td>
    
       <td>simplifiedmessage<textarea rows="3" cols="20" readonly class="url" name="simplified[]">simplifiedmessage</textarea> </td>
     <td>engmessage<textarea rows="3" cols="20" readonly class="url" name="engmessage[]">engmessage</textarea> </td>
    
    </tr>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry abt the mess of the code snippet, still very new in coding

Comment: Its ok .its a beginners problem.We  are all faced that  .My answer is useful [mark it as a answer](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJx-DJ1ezUAhVGLY8KHeNpCqQQFggnMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fsomeone-answers&usg=AFQjCNHZ4IpbyGACPNwGrF1LYJUvBvZJGw).it helpful for future visitors @Codezzz Happy coding.

Comment: can i ask you one more thing,i have added 2 more columns with different content. But when i click the button the 2nd and 3rd column textarea all become the same as the 1st textarea, any idea? Many thanks

Comment: yes .beacuse the class name of the 2nd & 3rd  is same as a first one .try to change the different one or use with `eq(0)` .check my updated answer

Comment: The thing is i want all 3 column to get the same input from .nextdate, but at the same time i'd like each of the 3 column to keep its own unique message in the beginning of the textarea box